# Counting and Grouping Strings in Drools Expert 6.5, with accumulate or collect keyword

Tags: java, java-stream, drools

How to compute the percentage of Vs in a list with drools rules. In case of percentage  of V are 80%, then fire a drools rule.

I have a ArrayList that will have only two values: V and N.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

How  to count the number of  V with drools rules, every V and N will worth 1, get total sum sum of V and N.

In java

```
  Map<String, Long> counted = list.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println("Counted: "+counted);
```

The expression above prints

> Counted: {V=4, N=15}

After get the the values, there will be an drols rule expression, which in case of 80 % occurrence the count V appearance prints "ok" otherwise prints not allowed.

Comment: What is your question? Also I'm not sure what you mean by *"the average of 80% of V appearance"*.

Comment: ok well, thanks for you comment. Just I need to get de average of V, if  it is 80 the rule will fire and prints ok

Comment: "V" is a string. What are you trying to get the average of from it?

Comment: Each V will be worth 1

Comment: If each V is worth 1, then the average of all the Vs will be 1.

Comment: Yes the sum of all V and N and after get the average count of V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132140/discussion-between-4castle-and-csstugfurher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rule that computes the percentage of Vs in the list:

```
rule "countVN"
when
  $vn: ArrayList( $s: size )
  accumulate( String( toString == "V" ) from $vn;
              $cnt: count( 1 );
              $cnt.doubleValue()/$s >= 0.8 )
then
  System.out.println( "80% or more" );
end
```

This fires just for the >= 80% case. If you need a result in any case, use

```
  ...
  accumulate( String( toString == "V" ) from $vn;
              $cnt: count( 1 ))
then
  if( $cnt.doubleValue()/$s >= 0.8 ) ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Throws [Line: 50, Column: 4]], Message [id=4, kieBase=kbase1, level=ERROR, path=rules.drl, line=50, column=0
   text=Unable to analyze expression '$cnt.doubleValue()/$s'], Message [id=5, kieBase=kbase1, level=ERROR, path=rules.drl, line=50, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression $cnt.doubleValue()/$s >= 0.8:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.$s()]
[Near : {... $cnt.doubleValue()/$s >= 0.8 ....}]
                                ^

Comment: My rule doesn't throw an exception, I have tested it using Drools 6.2. Please post the full text of the rule as you have it in your DRL code - not in a comment; edit it into your question.

Comment: I've  changed ; by ,  and everything workd fine in drools 6.5